# asp.net email sending from database vs website

Tags: asp.net, email

What is the good practice to email sending from database side or from website?
Before we use stored proc, and use db to send email(msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail) and this is easy to tracking from db side.
Now we use Entity Framework, it's easy to do the email sending at code side. but I have to make own table to track it.
So, what is the good way?

Comment: You can always drop the data in a table as use a trigger on the table. :)

Comment: Thanks, trigger is a option. But is that a good practice?

Comment: Well it is a centralized location, and pulls the logic away from the development team.  It does allow for easy tracking and reporting. About half of the companies that I have consulted for prefer it.  I cannot say good practice or bad practice.  I am sure a lot of people can give you their opinion on it.  i

Comment: Thanks a lot Lawrence, what does the other half companies prefer? I mean do you know any other options besides this one.

Comment: There is no right or wrong answer. It just depends on your needs. Find something that works well for you and then use that.